# How to make for Pageviewcontroller background transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

How to make for Pageviewcontroller background transparent,
I am trying here to make it transparent

```
  super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pageviewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageviewcontroller.dataSource = self
    self.pageviewcontroller.delegate = self
    var pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.backgroundColor = .clear
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
   pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    ViewControllers.append(
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
            instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! BaseViewController)
    
    
    
    
    ViewControllers.append(
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
            instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "qwertyViewController") as! BaseViewController)
    if let firstViewController = ViewControllers.first {
```

[image: trying to making that controller as transparent]

[image: after adding pagecontrol]

Answer (score 0):

**I've tested the following code and it works**

> This is my controller class:

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
```

> In that class I've created this variable:

```
lazy var pageArra: [UIViewController] = {
       return[self.VCInstance("ONE"),self.VCInstance("TWO"),self.VCInstance("THREE"),self.VCInstance("FOUR")]
    }()
```

> Which uses this function to get the storyboard assets. I gave 4 ViewControllers the ID's listed above

```
private func VCInstance(_ name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    }
```

> This is my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
    delegate = self
    var pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

> And This is how I get it to clear when it loads

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        } else if view is UIPageControl {
            view.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
}
```

**Plus all of the datasource and delegate required methods**

Comment: I am using Pageview controllers inbuilt it has page control right

Comment: I've edited the answer to give you an easy fix. Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Page control  color changed but background not got set to clear the answer not worked.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,NO use with that also

Comment: here issue is not with map view and one more view in page view controller both are showing the same, mapview is constrained to size of window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167425/discussion-between-siva-kumar-and-jake).